# BigQuery Pagepath into column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, transform

In bigquery we have data from google analytics.
We have column named as hits.pagepath.
It's like which pages visited by user in 1 session.
Is there anyway I can translate this row into column?
Like if user A visited to page x,y,z
I want this pages data into 2 columns First Page and Next Page.
Client_ID First_Page  Next_Page
A         x            y
A         y            z

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Do you want x,y,z pages to be dynamic or are they predefined?

Comment: x,y,z are page on website. We have many pages on the website.

Comment: Could you share what is your current data and the desired output so I can perform some tests?

Comment: I got the answer by using lead() function as suggested by Gordon Linoff. Thanks to all who tried to help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`lead()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#lead):

```
select t.*,
       lead(hits.pagepath) over (partition by client_id, session order by <visit order>) as next_pagepath
from t;
```

The `order by` should be using the column that specifies the ordering, presumably a timestamp or something similar.